# Interaction with scripts over stdin stdout and stdr in python

Tags: python, shell

Which python library i could use to interact with interactive shell scripts/binaries.

For example, how i could run

```
sudo bla bla bla
```

from python and next write password to subprocess stdin if sudo ask it?

Update.
I will try [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/) library.

Comment: It would be much safer to require the user to call the script with `sudo python script.py` and have him enter the password at the command-line, than it would be to include the sudo password inside the script.

Comment: Sudo is only example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is what i want!

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a very special case, as `sudo` reads the password from the terminal -- not from stdin. So a simple redirection is not suitable for that task.

However there is a little know feature of sudo, allowing to invoke an external program to read the password. This is *absolutly not* something I would encourage, but if you really want to do that, and are confortable with the idea of storing a password in plain text as part of a script, you might go that way:

1. Prepare an helper script to send the password:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   echo "p@sswd"
   ```
2. From Python, set `SUDO_ASKPASS` to your helper script and,
3. invoke `sudo -A`

   ```
   >>> import os
   >>> import subprocess
   >>> os.environ['SUDO_ASKPASS'] = '/path/to/your/helper/script.sh'
   >>> subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/sudo", "-A", ....])
   ```